# Entity Framework Convert String to Int

Tags: c#, entity-framework, comparison

In my where clause of a query I am trying to compare a column with a type of varchar, which contains numbers, to a predetermined integer. I want the ones that are greater than the predetermined number.

From what I've researched it's not possible to do this, as the standard functions are not available in SQL.

Can anyone suggest a way I can do this?

The line in *** is where I am trying to do the comparison. SVNREVISION is the string storing numeric characters.

```
.Where(
    @t =>
    @t.@t.@t.@t.a.MAINTBRANCH == 197 && @t.e.FIELDID == 106011301 ***&& @t.@t.@t.@t.a.SVNREVISION > 42544***
    && (@t.@t.@t.@t.a.CSEBRANCHCHANGE ?? "") != ""
    && !(@t.@t.@t.@t.a.CSEBRANCHCHANGE ?? "").Contains("DF"))
.Select(
    @t =>
```

Unfortunately it's not possible for me to change the data type of SVNREVISION.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do the filtering *in memory* instead of converting it into a SQL statement. You do it by forcing Entity Framework to evaluate the expression *before* you invoke the `Where` method by adding `ToList()`:

```
.ToList()
.Where(
    @t =>
    @t.@t.@t.@t.a.MAINTBRANCH == 197 && @t.e.FIELDID == 106011301 && Convert.ToInt32(@t.@t.@t.@t.a.SVNREVISION) > 42544
    && (@t.@t.@t.@t.a.CSEBRANCHCHANGE ?? "") != ""
    && !(@t.@t.@t.@t.a.CSEBRANCHCHANGE ?? "").Contains("DF"))
.Select(
    @t =>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response however this doesn't work - I get an error - can't use > on type string and int.